# parsing xml code and redirecting to table/file

Tags: oracle, parsing, plsql, xmltype

Below is the sample XML Code stored in Oracle column

```
<productAttribute> 
    <name>Baiying_attr_03</name> 
    <required>false</required> 
</productAttribute> 
<productAttribute> 
    <name>Baiying_attr_04</name> 
    <required>false</required> 
</productAttribute>
<productAttribute> 
    <name>Baiying_attr_05</name> 
    <required>false</required> 
</productAttribute>
```

I want to parse this xml code and spool data in file as node by node something like

Expected Ouput

```
Baiying_attr_03,false 
Baiying_attr_04,false 
Baiying_attr_05,false
```

Actually I am getting as

```
Baiying_attr_03falseBaiying_attr_04falseBaiying_attr_05false
```

I tried to fetch data in cursor but I am getting all this data in single transaction so can't split. If I want to get output as below then what should I use

Following was my code

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
    data_text VARCHAR2(32765);
    CURSOR c1 IS  
    SELECT XMLTYPE(XMLDATA).EXTRACT('//productAttribute/text()').getStringVal() 
    FROM TABLE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO data_text;  
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(data_text);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1; 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this closer to the output you want?

```
/* 
NAME                           REQUIRED                      
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Baiying_attr_03                false                         
Baiying_attr_04                false                         
Baiying_attr_05                false                         

3 rows selected.

*** Note: I added ROWSET tags around your XML Code *** */

   select lines.*
    from (select xmltype(
          '<ROWSET><productAttribute><name>Baiying_attr_03</name><required>false</required> </productAttribute> <productAttribute> <name>Baiying_attr_04</name> <required>false</required> </productAttribute> <productAttribute> <name>Baiying_attr_05</name> <required>false</required> </productAttribute></ROWSET>') as the_xml
  from dual) zz,
         xmltable('for $i in /ROWSET/productAttribute
                 return $i' PASSING 
                   zz.the_xml  COLUMNS name varchar2(30) PATH 'name', required varchar2(30) PATH 'required') lines;
```